# Scala pickle case class with objectId

Tags: scala, pickle

```
case class Test(test: ObjectId)
val test = Test(new ObjectId)
test.pickle.value
```

but then I got error:

```
error: Cannot generate a pickler for Test. Recompile with -Xlog-implicits for details
              test.pickle
```

any suggestions how to deal with such types ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information on ObjectId? What library is this coming from?

Comment: org.bson.types.objectId